# Error checking for STRICT_TRANS_TABLES variables that won't save

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very sizeable PHP website with over 100, and some pretty big, **MySQL** tables. After my host, which was restricting me to running **PHP 5.6** and **MySQL 5.4** previously, notified me they were canceling my dedicated server in 14 days to move everyone to "the cloud", I had to move hosting site as it needs root access, and essentially upgraded to **PHP 7.3** and **MySQL 5.7**. I went from the loosey-goosey fun mode of **MySQL 5.4** to using STRICT_TRANS_TABLES mode of **MySQL 5.7** with the new host. So now I'm scrambling to update everything to comply with `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`. I don't want to disable `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` as it is the future. However, even after type settings nearly all data types, there are still some pages that won't save data correctly.

That is to say, the screen refreshes as though is does save correctly, but the values do not actually get written to the databases.

My question is, what's the best way to trouble shoot such tables that aren't saving the values passed? Is there an error log I can enable or some debugging tool? Or is it just a matter of eliminating variables until I find the 'trouble child' (as I'm doing now, but it's a long and tedious process as the tables are large)?

Comment: Ensure [log_error_verbosity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_error_verbosity) is set to 3 (probably is). Bit inconvenient to try to do this in 14 days however there's consequences in deferring maintenance from a 5.4 instance so long. If you'd gone mariadb I'd suggest [SQL Error Log Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-error-log-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The log_error_verbosity is set to 3 and I'm using MySQLi